# WPengine not allowing to connect redis with scalegrid cluster

Tags: wordpress, phpredis

I have setup with scalegrid redis cluster with wordpress. but my wp-engine WordPress site unable to connect with scale grid cluster for the `Wp object cache` plugin

I am getting this issue

```
Status: Not connected
Client: PhpRedis (v5.3.1)
Drop-in: Valid
Disabled: No
Ping: 
Connection Exception: Connection refused (RedisException)
Errors: [
    "Connection refused"
]
PhpRedis: 5.3.1
Predis: Not loaded
Credis: Not loaded
PHP Version: 7.4.14
Plugin Version: 2.0.17
Redis Version: Unknown
Multisite: No
Filesystem: Working
Global Prefix: "wp_"
Blog Prefix: "wp_"
WP_REDIS_DISABLED: false
WP_REDIS_PREFIX: "8820f86645f21b76"
WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT: "8820f86645f21b76"
Global Groups: [
    "blog-details",
    "blog-id-cache",
    "blog-lookup",
    "global-posts",
    "networks",
    "rss",
    "sites",
    "site-details",
    "site-lookup",
    "site-options",
    "site-transient",
    "users",
    "useremail",
    "userlogins",
    "usermeta",
    "user_meta",
    "userslugs",
    "redis-cache"
]
Ignored Groups: [
    "counts",
    "plugins",
    "themes",
    "blog-details",
    "blog-id-cache",
    "blog-lookup",
    "global-posts",
    "networks",
    "rss",
    "sites",
    "site-details",
    "site-lookup",
    "site-options",
    "site-transient",
    "users",
    "useremail",
    "userlogins",
    "usermeta",
    "user_meta",
    "userslugs",
    "redis-cache",
    "blog_meta",
    "tribe-events-non-persistent",
    "avada"
]
Unflushable Groups: []
Drop-ins: [
    "advanced-cache.php v by ",
    "Redis Object Cache Drop-In v2.0.17 by Till Krüss"
]
```

Is anyone resolve this issue?

Note: I didn't install redis-cli on wp-engine.in my case i am using scalegrid cluster to connect with plugin.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solved this, by making changes in the scale grid Redis cluster.

just for other developer's context, make sure that you have created new cluster without `-- tls` after making this change connection won't get refused with the wp-cache object plugin.

also as per the https://help.scalegrid.io/docs/redis-cli-tool-installation-use
document make sure that you can able to make a connection with sg-cli.

Answer (score 0):

ScaleGrid has a blog post to address just this use case: [Using Redis
Object Cache to Speed Up Your WordPress Installation](https://scalegrid.io/blog/using-redis-object-cache-to-speed-up-your-wordpress-installation/). Does this help?

From the article, this is the minimal configuration required.

```
define('WP_REDIS_HOST', '<your-ScaleGrid-Hostname>');
define('WP_REDIS_PASSWORD', '<your-ScaleGrid-Password>');
```

A good starting point would probably be strip your configuration file to just this, and see if that helps?

Other than that, there isn't much information to go on. The error seems to
indicate a network error - have you verified if network connectivity is
proper? One option would be to install redis CLI on your WP machine and attempt connecting via it. That would help narrow down if the issue is with PHP/WordPress or connectivity/configuration

You could also check the logs on the Redis server side to check for any errors. If you haven't already, maybe reach out to support@scalegrid.io so they can debug this for you?